# How to make Thor find templates for system installed .thor files?

Tags: ruby, thor

I've created a `.thor` script for setting up a new ruby project just the way I like it. I'm using the Thor::Actions `directory` command to build the app entirely from a template directory structure, as opposed to defining them inline with heredocs. The script directory looks something like this:

```
rubynu.thor
template/
  bin/
  lib/
    %app_name%.rb.tt
    %app_name%
  README.markdown
  .gitignore
  ...
```

This works really great, and lets me easily visualize and change individual parts of the template as my taste changes.

But I can't figure out a nice way to get thor to find the template directory once the `.thor` file is system installed using `thor install rubynu.thor`. Install sticks a copy of the `.thor` file into `~/.thor` but ignores the `template/` directory, and so the templates aren't found anymore.

I don't want to hardcode the `source_root` path or manually copy over the template directory to `~/.thor`. Is there something built-in to thor that handles installing templates along with the `.thor` file? It would be great if they could be packaged together when installed.

If not, what is the nicest way to get around this? Surely there are system installed thor tasks somewhere that use template files. How'd you do it? I suppose I could bypass `thor install` and provide this as a gem (though that seems like overkill), or bite the bullet and stick all the template definitions inline in a giant `.thor` file (less pleasant to make changes to the structure later).

For reference, here is the simple `.thor` file I'm using:

```
class Rubynu < Thor::Group
  include Thor::Actions

  argument :app_name

  def self.source_root
    File.dirname(__FILE__)
  end

  def apply_directory_template
    directory 'template', app_name
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set up your `.thor` file like this:

```
<my_thor_commands>/
  templates/
    bin/
    lib/
    ...
   main.thor
```

`thor install <my_thor_command>` will look for a file called `main.thor`, and then install it and anything else in `<my_thor_command>`. After that, you can rely on:

```
def self.source_root
  File.dirname(__FILE__)
end
```

which will give you the path to the `<my_thor_command>` as it was installed.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping to hear. It works perfectly, thanks man!